# haskell monad case example

Tags: haskell

How do I check a client?

```
case e of
    Just e -> let client = (e, sink)
    Nothing -> let client = false

case msg of
    _   | not client -> do nothing
        | msg -> do something
        | otherwise -> do print "i was born in..."
```

Probably not even close but hope its clear what I wanted to do.

Comment: it's called monad, not nomad.

Comment: doh! :) I have a feeling this is going to be a complicated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
m e sink = do
    case e of
        Nothing -> print "No Client"
        (Just c) -> do
            -- Client is in c
```

If it isn't, we really need more code and description about what you are trying to do.

Otherwise, I have to tell you, it seems like you're doing imperative stuff in Haskell. You should go back and read some tutorials, like [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/). Especially the latter contains a lot of Haskell application examples about actual Haskell programs.

Comment: imperative most of the time helps me to explain what i am trying to achieve :)

Comment: Haskell works entirely different to C or Java in that respect. You cannot assign values like you do there. Anything in Haskell has to be outcome of a function. I don't know if you understood the concept there.

Comment: so m will return c or print something right? But how do you check in a guard (second case) that m was successful? If not clear i will use a real world example trying to explain.

Comment: no, `m` is of type `IO ()`. Where I put the comment, there is the point you have a `c` which you can use for the further work.

Comment: so in the second case i can do `_ | not c -> do print "hello"` Can you expand the answer please with a second case that checks for c

Comment: `c` is already checked for. With the `case` above, you have a valid `c`. You don't have to check for it like you do in JavaScript, because Haskell is strictly typed. If you have a `(Just c)`, you have a valid `c`. If you have a `Nothing`, the `c` was invalid and thus you never get to see it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14571/discussion-between-lambda-dusk-and-gert-cuykens)